# Merge one row of a df to multiple duplicate tstamp rows of another df based on nearest tstamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  two df's :

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'tstamp': ['12-11-2021 00:00:00','12-11-2021 00:00:00','12-11-2021 01:00:00','12-11-2021 01:00:00'],'band_name': ['A','B','A','B'],'band_values' : [1,2,3,4]})

df2 = pd.Dataframe({'tstamp': ['12-11-2021 00:10:00','12-11-2021 00:20:00','12-11-2021 01:10:00','12-11-2021 01:20:00','12-11-2021 01:30:00'],'mgr_name': ['John','Nick','Jack','Jayce','Mark'],['mgr_surname': ['Hanks','Lad','Ors','Lancelot','Larks']})
```

and i want to merge the two dfs based on nearest tstamp and add all duplicates tstamps with values from df1 to df2, so the final format of the table will be like this:

| tstamp | mgr_name | mgr_surname | band_name | band_values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-11-2021 00:10:00 | John | Hanks | A | 1 |
| 12-11-2021 00:10:00 | John | Hanks | B | 2 |
| 12-11-2021 00:20:00 | Nick | Lad | A | 1 |
| 12-11-2021 00:20:00 | Nick | Lad | B | 2 |
| 12-11-2021 01:10:00 | Jack | Ors | A | 3 |
| 12-11-2021 01:10:00 | Jack | Ors | B | 4 |
| 12-11-2021 01:20:00 | Jayce | Lancelot | A | 3 |
| 12-11-2021 01:20:00 | Jayce | Lancelot | B | 4 |
| 12-11-2021 01:30:00 | Mark | Larks | A | 3 |
| 12-11-2021 01:30:00 | Mark | Larks | B | 4 |

I tried to do : `df = pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,on='tstamp', direction='nearest')`

but it doesn't merge the duplicates tstamps.

PS: the real size of df's is df2 > df1 so i need the whole data of df2.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you just need to invert the order of the merge:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='tstamp', direction='nearest')
```

output:

```
      tstamp band_name  band_values mgr_name mgr_surname
0 2021-12-11         A            1     John       Hanks
1 2021-12-11         B            2     John       Hanks
2 2021-12-11         C            3     John       Hanks
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but i forgot to mention that the real size of dfs is df2 > df1.  so i need the whole data of df2

Comment: The you should provide a complete example, (please post reproducible code, for now it is a pain to construct the dataframes)

Comment: ok,  i edited , i hope its more clear now